# NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for #<Proc: ...> with Faraday

Tags: ruby, faraday

I want to send a get request with a JSON body (for search) using Faraday, but am getting the above error. I thought that `self` inside the Proc was messing things up, but that had nothing to do with it. I'm following the documentation on the [faraday github page][1] but have gotten stuck on this.

```
def perform_query
  response = self.database.connection.get do |request|
    request.url self.path
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    request.body(self.to_json)
  end
end

def terms_to_json
  terms_array = self.terms.keys.inject([]) do |terms_array, field|
    value = self.terms[field]
    terms_array.tap do |ary|
      if value
        ary << "\"#{field}\": \"#{value}\""
      end 
    end
  end

  "{ #{terms_array.join ','} }"
end

def to_json
  "{ \"queryb\" : #{self.terms_to_json} }"
end
```

Here is the stack trace, with the error coming somewhere in the get Proc in `#perform_query` :

```
from /Users/chrismaddox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/faraday-0.8.1/lib/faraday/request.rb:60:in `url'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/faraday-0.8.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:219:in `block in run_request'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/faraday-0.8.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:237:in `block in build_request'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/faraday-0.8.1/lib/faraday/request.rb:35:in `block in create'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/faraday-0.8.1/lib/faraday/request.rb:34:in `tap'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/faraday-0.8.1/lib/faraday/request.rb:34:in `create'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/faraday-0.8.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:233:in `build_request'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/faraday-0.8.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:218:in `run_request'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/faraday-0.8.1/lib/faraday/connection.rb:87:in `get'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/Dropbox/LivingSocial/Hungry Academy/Projects/hackchat/search_ruby/elastic.rb:83:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/Dropbox/LivingSocial/Hungry Academy/Projects/hackchat/search_ruby/elastic.rb:112:in `perform_query'
    from /Users/chrismaddox/Dropbox/LivingSocial/Hungry Academy/Projects/hackchat/search_ruby/elastic.rb:61:in `send_query'
```

UPDATE:

the path method returns a string of the path to the search for a given index. Eg `/wombats/animals/_search`

Elastic::Database#path calls Elastic::Index#index_path:

```
module Elastic
  ELASTIC_URL = "http://localhost:9200"


  class Index
    attr_reader :index_name, :type_name, :last

    def initialize(type)
      @index_name = "#{type}-index"
      @type_name = type
      @last = 0
      add_to_elastic
    end

    def add_to_elastic
      index_url = URI.parse "#{ELASTIC_URL}#{index_path}/"
      Connection.new(index_url).put()
    end

    def index_path
      "/#{self.index_name}"
    end

    def search_path
      "#{type_path}/_search/"
    end

    def type_path
      "#{self.index_path}/#{type_name}/"
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Judging from the stack trace your `path` method might be returning something fishy. What does it look like?

Comment: Okay I added the path methods to the question

Comment: It may be better to post what the path *contains*, not what the code to generate it is.

Comment: Okay updated what it looks like

Comment: I'd still like to see the code for the path method

Comment: Shouldn't "terms_array.tap" be "terms_array.map!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to search_path = `"#{type_path}/_search/"`
A call to type_path = `"#{self.index_path}/#{type_name}/"`
A call to index_path = `"/#{self.index_name}"`

So if index name is wombat and type name is animal, search_path evaluates to `/wombat/animal//_search`

It turns out that this wasn't the problem showing the error, but was caused because Faraday's methods are inconsistent. `Faraday::Request#url` and `Faraday::Request#headers` are themselves setter methods, whereas `Faraday::Request#body=` is the setter method for body.